# user permissions needed for token access to kubernetes dashboard with RBAC

Tags: proxy, kubernetes, token, dashboard, kubectl

On kubernetes 1.8.4 I'm trying to give kubernetes users access to our dashboard.

When using the admin context to proxy, all the tokens work when logging into the dashboard. But my users don't have the admin context, only I do, so they use their own context to proxy. And in those situations, they get an error.

**Steps:**

1. Create a service account for a user, put token in `~/.kube/config`
2. Give permissions to namespace A to that service account through rolebinding
3. Switch to that user's context
4. Do deployments, get pod overview, etc, verify it works. all fine so far
5. Start `kubectl` proxy, still in that user's context
6. Open browser, go to http://localhost:8001/ui
7. See this in the browser:

   ```
   {
     "kind": "Status",
     "apiVersion": "v1",
     "metadata": {},
     "status": "Failure",
     "message": "
         forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:<username>\"
             cannot get path \"/ui\"",
     "reason": "Forbidden",
     "details": {},
     "code": 403
   }
   ```
8. try http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
9. See this in the browser:

   ```
   {
     "kind": "Status",
     "apiVersion": "v1",
     "metadata": {},
     "status": "Failure",
     "message": "
         services \"https:kubernetes-dashboard:\" is forbidden:
         User \"system:serviceaccount:default:<username>\" cannot get services/proxy in the namespace \"kube-system\"",
     "reason": "Forbidden",
     "details": {
       "name": "https:kubernetes-dashboard:",
       "kind": "services"
     },
     "code": 403
   }
   ```

Clearly a permission problem. I'm not sure which permission the user needs to have to enable them to access the dashboard though. I'm very hesitant to give them permissions into the kube-system namespace.

When I stop kubectl proxy and then switch to the admin context, start the proxy and retry the same url, I get the dashboard login page.

What do I need to do to get that same result when using the user's context?

Comment: `/ui` is deprecated, see https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard#getting-started .. use the full url instead: http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

Comment: Are you aware of http://docs.heptio.com/content/tutorials/rbac.html yes?

Comment: @fishi similar result with the proper url, I've updated the question with that info, thanks.

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas yes, I know how to write RBAC policies and apply them, but in this particular case I don't know which policy I would need to set to make this work, besides giving full admin access. I'm confident I'm not the first nor only person wanting to give only the least required privileges to a service account for accessing the dashboard, so someone probably already figured this out.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a different way other than providing some access to kube-system, so I did using the following role and binding:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  namespace: kube-system
  name: user-role-dashboard
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - services
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - services/proxy
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create"]

---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  namespace: kube-system
  name: user-binding-dashboard
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: system:serviceaccount:<namespace>:<username>
  apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: user-role-dashboard
  apiGroup: ""
```

Would still like to know whether there is a better way though, your thoughts and suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation and found my answer in this post: [Kubernetes Dashboard Installation Deep Dive](http://www.joseluisgomez.com/containers/kubernetes-dashboard/). It worked perfectly.

The idea is to create a PKCS #12 file from the kubernetes-admin user's certificate and key. Import this into your browser, then access the dashboard through the API server (I did not use a proxy). Note that SKIP will not grant any access. Login using the bearer token as normal, and the dashboard rights are restricted by the user's token.